# Oracle Flexcube Direct Banking fldPassword Decryption

Tags: oracle

Am conducting a penetration test on Oracle flexcube direct banking solution. I managed to retrive a users login dump from the system however the fldPassword value is encrypted.

If i have the fldPassword=value and fldEncrKey=value. How is it possible to decrypt fldPassword?

Comment: Actually i got this after a long while. Not so sure about the decrypting bit but i realised that usinga proxy such as tamper data you can just directly feed in the hash with the encryption key to log in.

Answer (score 0):

Oracle FCDB user's password can't be decrypt back because FCDB password encryption/hashing is a one-way trip. During authentication the plain input password decrypt and compare with the stored fldPassword.